# Application (tomcat) stops responding after a while when using JVM Open J9

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7, openj9

I'm using Open J9 and after a while running my application stops responding .. In production occurs after 2 hours, locally managed to simulate using JMeter. The application (tomcat) simply stops responding and I need to restart to get it back. The problem is that nothing appears in the logs (catalina and log4j) to help me with the investigation.
I have the core dump and the GC log.

```
0SECTION       TITLE subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ===============================
1TICHARSET     UTF-8
1TISIGINFO     Dump Event "user" (00004000) received 
1TIDATETIME    Date: 2019/10/11 at 09:37:45:772
1TINANOTIME    System nanotime: 227236303608900
1TIFILENAME    Javacore filename:    //javacore.20191011.093745.54545.0001.txt
1TIREQFLAGS    Request Flags: 0x81 (exclusive+preempt)
1TIPREPSTATE   Prep State: 0x104 (exclusive_vm_access+trace_disabled)
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       GPINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           ================================
2XHOSLEVEL     OS Level         : Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit
2XHCPUS        Processors -
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : amd64
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 3
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
NULL           
1XHERROR2      Register dump section only produced for SIGSEGV, SIGILL or SIGFPE.
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       ENVINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1CIJAVAVERSION JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
1CIVMVERSION   20190717_368
1CIJ9VMTAG     openj9-0.15.1
1CIJ9VMVERSION 0f66c6431
1CIJITVERSION  0f66c6431
1CIOMRVERSION  ec782f26_CMPRSS
1CIJCLVERSION  f147086df1e based on jdk8u222-b10
1CIJITMODES    JIT enabled, AOT enabled, FSD enabled, HCR enabled
1CIRUNNINGAS   Running as a standalone JVM
1CIVMIDLESTATE VM Idle State: IDLE
1CICONTINFO    Running in container : TRUE
1CICGRPINFO    JVM support for cgroups enabled : TRUE
1CISTARTTIME   JVM start time: 2019/10/10 at 18:55:29:459
1CISTARTNANO   JVM start nanotime: 174300841862300
1CIPROCESSID   Process ID: 54545 (0xD511)
1CICMDLINE     [not available]
1CIJAVAHOMEDIR Java Home Dir:   /usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre
1CIJAVADLLDIR  Java DLL Dir:    /usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/bin
1CISYSCP       Sys Classpath:   /usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/jclSC180/vm.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/se-service.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/rt.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/resources.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/jsse.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/charsets.jar;/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/jce.jar;
1CIUSERARGS    UserArgs:
2CIUSERARG               -Xoptionsfile=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/options.default
2CIUSERARG               -Xlockword:mode=default,noLockword=java/lang/String,noLockword=java/util/MapEntry,noLockword=java/util/HashMap$Entry,noLockword=org/apache/harmony/luni/util/ModifiedMap$Entry,noLockword=java/util/Hashtable$Entry,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodType,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/CollectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConstructorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConvertHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ArgumentConversionHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/AsTypeHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ExplicitCastHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FilterReturnHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ReceiverBoundHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DynamicInvokerHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/IndirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InterfaceHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VirtualHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/PrimitiveHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeExactHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeGenericHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VarargsCollectorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ThunkTuple
2CIUSERARG               -Xjcl:jclse29
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.boot.library.path=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/se/apps/oracle-client:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.home=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/jre/lib/ext
2CIUSERARG               -Duser.dir=/
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.class.path=.
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
2CIUSERARG               -Xmx1024m
2CIUSERARG               -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.awt.headless=true
2CIUSERARG               -Xdebug
2CIUSERARG               -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
2CIUSERARG               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
2CIUSERARG               -XX:ErrorFile=/usr/local/se/log/platform_err_crash_%p.log
2CIUSERARG               -XX:+PrintGCDetails
2CIUSERARG               -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
2CIUSERARG               -Xloggc:/usr/local/se/log/gclogs_%p.log
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat/endorsed
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.class.path=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
2CIUSERARG               -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat
2CIUSERARG               -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat
2CIUSERARG               -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat/temp
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.command=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
2CIUSERARG               -Dsun.java.launcher.pid=54545
NULL
1CIUSERLIMITS  User Limits (in bytes except for NOFILE and NPROC)
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL           type                            soft limit           hard limit
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_AS                        unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_CORE                              0            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_CPU                       unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_DATA                      unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_FSIZE                     unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_LOCKS                     unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_MEMLOCK                    83968000             83968000
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_NOFILE                       200000               200000
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_NPROC                     unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_RSS                       unlimited            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_STACK                       8388608            unlimited
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE                     819200               819200
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_NICE                              0                    0
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_RTPRIO                            0                    0
2CIUSERLIMIT   RLIMIT_SIGPENDING                    15638                15638
NULL
1CIENVVARS     Environment Variables
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CIENVVAR      TERM=xterm
2CIENVVAR      CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/se/apps/tomcat
2CIENVVAR      NLS_LANG=BRAZILIAN PORTUGUESE_BRAZIL.WE8MSWIN1252
2CIENVVAR      SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=
2CIENVVAR      LC_ALL=pt_BR
2CIENVVAR      JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m -Djava.awt.headless=true
2CIENVVAR      LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/se/apps/oracle-client
2CIENVVAR      TNS_ADMIN=/usr/local/se/apps/oracle-client
2CIENVVAR      PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
2CIENVVAR      PWD=/
2CIENVVAR      JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10
2CIENVVAR      LANG=pt_BR
2CIENVVAR      CATALINA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -XX:ErrorFile=/usr/local/se/log/platform_err_crash_%p.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/usr/local/se/log/gclogs_%p.log
2CIENVVAR      SHLVL=2
2CIENVVAR      LC_CTYPE=ISO-8859-1
2CIENVVAR      SYSTEMCTL_IGNORE_DEPENDENCIES=
2CIENVVAR      ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/se/apps/oracle-client
2CIENVVAR      _=/usr/local/se/apps/java/jdk8u222-b10/bin/java
2CIENVVAR      HOME=
NULL           
1CISYSINFO     System Information
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CISYSINFO     Hypervisor name = Hyper-V
2CISYSINFO     /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern = core
2CISYSINFO     /proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid = 0
NULL           
1CICPUINFO     CPU Information
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CIPHYSCPU     Physical CPUs: 3
2CIONLNCPU     Online CPUs: 3
2CIBOUNDCPU    Bound CPUs: 3
2CIACTIVECPU   Active CPUs: 0
2CITARGETCPU   Target CPUs: 3
NULL 
1CICGRPINFO    Cgroup Information 
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2CICGRPINFO    subsystem : cpuset
2CICGRPINFO    cgroup name : /
3CICGRPINFO        CPU exclusive : 0
3CICGRPINFO        Mem exclusive : 0
3CICGRPINFO        CPUs : 0-2
3CICGRPINFO        Mems : 0
2CICGRPINFO    subsystem : memory
2CICGRPINFO    cgroup name : /
3CICGRPINFO        Memory Limit : Not Set
3CICGRPINFO        Memory + Swap Limit : Not Set
3CICGRPINFO        Memory Usage : 2825285632 bytes
3CICGRPINFO        Memory + Swap Usage : 2825281536 bytes
3CICGRPINFO        Memory Max Usage : 3476606976 bytes
3CICGRPINFO        Memory + Swap Max Usage : 3476606976 bytes
3CICGRPINFO        Memory limit exceeded count : 0
3CICGRPINFO        Memory + Swap limit exceeded count : 0
3CICGRPINFO        OOM Killer Disabled : 0
3CICGRPINFO        Under OOM : 0
2CICGRPINFO    subsystem : cpu
2CICGRPINFO    cgroup name : /
3CICGRPINFO        CPU Period : 100000 microseconds
3CICGRPINFO        CPU Quota : Not Set
3CICGRPINFO        CPU Shares : 1024
3CICGRPINFO        Period intervals elapsed count : 0
3CICGRPINFO        Throttled count : 0
3CICGRPINFO        Total throttle time : 0 nanoseconds
NULL           
NULL           ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       NATIVEMEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
0MEMUSER
1MEMUSER       JRE: 2,083,821,918 bytes / 93947 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--VM: 1,520,901,302 bytes / 88825 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Classes: 189,760,160 bytes / 11927 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Memory Manager (GC): 1,101,772,744 bytes / 3251 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Heap: 1,073,803,264 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 27,969,480 bytes / 3250 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Threads: 83,974,742 bytes / 1321 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Stack: 7,789,168 bytes / 259 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Native Stack: 74,317,824 bytes / 260 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 1,867,750 bytes / 802 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Trace: 2,262,616 bytes / 994 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JVMTI: 6,806,024 bytes / 63280 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--JVMTI Allocate(): 6,761,576 bytes / 63249 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 44,448 bytes / 31 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JNI: 2,431,312 bytes / 6094 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Port Library: 130,819,968 bytes / 129 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Unused <32bit allocation regions: 130,799,920 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 20,048 bytes / 128 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 3,073,736 bytes / 1829 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--JIT: 460,598,208 bytes / 4838 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 268,435,456 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 125,832,960 bytes / 60 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 66,329,792 bytes / 4777 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--Class Libraries: 102,322,408 bytes / 284 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--VM Class Libraries: 102,322,408 bytes / 284 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--sun.misc.Unsafe: 101,301,656 bytes / 36 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Direct Byte Buffers: 40,232 bytes / 9 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Other: 101,261,424 bytes / 27 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 1,020,752 bytes / 248 allocations
NULL           
NULL
```

Comment: Can you capture two (or more) javacore files a minute apart and then look at the threads section of the javacore.  If all the threads are in the same place then there is likely a dead lock of some sort occurring.  Sharing the javacores and a system core with the OpenJ9 community will help to narrow down the cause

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I shared what I have in the Open J9 slack, I will generate more dumps and share new information.